# how do i pass a variable from a pop up window to the window that opened it using only JS

Tags: javascript, web, cross-domain, popupwindow

I have a window that opens up a page, that is of a different domain,  in a popup window. i would like this pop up window to return a variable to the previous page. How do i accomplish this ? I've tried using cookies, worked successfully, but people say it won't exactly suffice for an application on the production line (security implications).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an API/ grant access to your backend from the other domain. and send by the Backend the requested Data.